# wrong calculation of incircles in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

In redrawing [a geometric figure](http://people.missouristate.edu/LesReid/POW24.html?fbclid=IwAR2T8aQmgXW3S1oL_5iDEh-04Cjnqa2TVxy3qzKAWpkddaDO7wv3RDiU4BI) with TikZ, it seems that some wrong calculation in tkz-euclide with incircles (the red color below). The command

```
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](A2,B2,C2)
```

give different circles when I change the order, such as (C2,B2,A2). Morover, a blank before (A2,B2,C2)

```
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red] (A2,B2,C2)
```

results an error.

Can you give some explanation/suggestion/improvement ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\def\a{3} % side of the equilateral triangle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\a/sqrt(3)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\pagecolor{yellow!20}
\path
(210:\d) coordinate (A0)
(330:\d) coordinate (B0)
(90:\d)  coordinate (C0)
($(C0)!.3!(B0)$) coordinate (A1)
($(A0)!.3!(C0)$) coordinate (B1)
($(B0)!.3!(A0)$) coordinate (C1)
(intersection of A0--A1 and B0--B1) coordinate (A2)
(intersection of B0--B1 and C0--C1) coordinate (B2)
(intersection of C0--C1 and A0--A1) coordinate (C2);

\clip (A0)--(B0)--(C0)--cycle;
\draw[cyan]
(A0)--(A1) (B0)--(B1) (C0)--(C1) 
(A0)--(B0)--(C0)--cycle;
\draw (A2)--(B2)--(C2)--cycle;

\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](A0,B0,A2)
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](B0,C0,B2) 
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](C0,A0,C2)

\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](A2,B2,C2)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](C2,B2,A2)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](B2,A2,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me it seems that this is almost a duplicate of [an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460483/121799), and the answer is, again, that I think that there are numerical instabilities in tkz-euclide. However, to my own embarrassment I have to admit that this is also true for one of my solutions presented there. In my solution (and I also think for tkz-euclide but my French is not sufficient to say this with certainty) the issue is that the on has to find the right quadrants, which I thought I did but apparently didn't. So I switched gears and used the [determination of the center based on Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Cartesian_coordinates), and there seems to be no issue.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{incircle/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={
let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$), \p2=($(#3)-(#1)$),\p3=($(#2)-(#3)$),
    \n1={0.5*(veclen(\x1,\y1)+veclen(\x2,\y2)+veclen(\x3,\y3))},
    \n2={sqrt(((\n1-veclen(\x1,\y1))/\n1))*sqrt((\n1-veclen(\x2,\y2))*(\n1-veclen(\x3,\y3)))},
    \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, % length #1 -- #2
    \n4={veclen(\x2,\y2)}, % length #1 -- #3
    \n5={veclen(\x3,\y3)}, % length #2 -- #3
    \n6={\n3+\n4+\n5}
    in % \pgfextra{\typeout{\n1,\n2,\n3,\n4,\n5,\n6}}
    (${(\n5/\n6)}*(#1)+{(\n4/\n6)}*(#2)+{(\n3/\n6)}*(#3)$) circle (\n2)
}}}
% \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
% \usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3} % side of the equilateral triangle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\a/sqrt(3)}
\pagecolor{yellow!20}
\path
(210:\d) coordinate (A0)
(330:\d) coordinate (B0)
(90:\d)  coordinate (C0)
($(C0)!.3!(B0)$) coordinate (A1)
($(A0)!.3!(C0)$) coordinate (B1)
($(B0)!.3!(A0)$) coordinate (C1)
(intersection cs:first line={(A0)--(A1)},second line={(B0)--(B1)}) coordinate (A2)
(intersection cs:first line={(B0)--(B1)},second line={(C0)--(C1)}) coordinate (B2)
(intersection cs:first line={(C0)--(C1)},second line={(A0)--(A1)}) coordinate (C2);

\begin{scope}
\clip (A0)--(B0)--(C0)--cycle;
\draw[cyan]
(A0)--(A1) (B0)--(B1) (C0)--(C1) 
(A0)--(B0)--(C0)--cycle;
\draw (A2)--(B2)--(C2)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[blue,incircle={A0}{B0}{A2}];
\draw[blue,incircle={B0}{C0}{B2}];
\draw[blue,incircle={C0}{A0}{C2}];
% \tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](A0,B0,A2)
% \tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](B0,C0,B2) 
% \tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](C0,A0,C2)

\draw[red,incircle={A2}{B2}{C2}];
%\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](A2,B2,C2)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](C2,B2,A2)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](B2,A2,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for pure TikZ answer! By the way, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460483/tikz-euclid-incircle-and-calculated-coordinates is not my question (that is other Black ^^). I did not notice that when posting question

Comment: @BlackMild Oh, sorry!! I changed it. Sorry again!

Comment: also I think that "determination of almost geometric figures based on Cartesian coordinates" be nice way of drawing of geometric figures, as geometry/olympiad module in Asymptote.

Comment: @BlackMild I agree with that. Probably no one wants to do that because it might be considered stepping on the toes of the author of `tkz-euclide`. This leaves us with the situation in which you are (almost, i.e. up to the above-mentioned issues) fine if you know French and less so if you don't. In principle one can do everything with `calc` but this requires one sometimes to punch in formulae and, what is worse, find out by trial and error which solution is most stable.

Comment: Is there a way to write \draw[blue,incircle={A}{B}{C}]; in better form, something like that \draw[blue] incircle{A}{B}{C}; or \draw[blue] incircle(A,B,C); ?

Comment: @BlackMild One would have to modify the parser of Ti*k*Z. This *can* be done, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34986/121799) and in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35050/121799) but I agree with the statement made there: **I still strongly recommend the to path solution. Do not subvert the TikZ code unless you know what you are doing.** (with "to path" replaced by "insert path").

Comment: Use \def\incenter(#1,#2,#3)(#4){...} command, we may store incenter of the triangle ABC to I with \incenter(A,B,C)(I). How can we store inradius of the triangle ABC to a variable (\r, for example), and then use \draw (I) circle(\r); ???

Comment: @BlackMild `\tikzset{incircle/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={
let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$), \p2=($(#3)-(#1)$),\p3=($(#2)-(#3)$),
    \n1={0.5*(veclen(\x1,\y1)+veclen(\x2,\y2)+veclen(\x3,\y3))},
    \n2={sqrt(((\n1-veclen(\x1,\y1))/\n1))*sqrt((\n1-veclen(\x2,\y2))*(\n1-veclen(\x3,\y3)))},
    \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, % length #1 -- #2
    \n4={veclen(\x2,\y2)}, % length #1 -- #3
    \n5={veclen(\x3,\y3)}, % length #2 -- #3
    \n6={\n3+\n4+\n5}
    in  \pgfextra{\xdef\BlackMildRadius{\n2}}
    (${(\n5/\n6)}*(#1)+{(\n4/\n6)}*(#2)+{(\n3/\n6)}*(#3)$)
 coordinate (incenter) circle (\n2)
}}}`

Comment: Then you can `\draw[red,dashed] (incenter) circle[radius=\BlackMildRadius];` after a blue circle.

Comment: Thanks! it works for the above code, but my question is a bit different. Let me make a new question!

Answer (score 4):

Bug in the last version 1.16 of tkz-eucide, with the next (beta actually) you get the result. You need to install tkz-base and tkz-euclide in texmf tree.

[v2.40b Euclide](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.40b.zip)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\def\a{3} % side of the equilateral triangle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\a/sqrt(3)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzDefPoint(210:\d){A0}
\tkzDefPoint(330:\d){B0}
\tkzDefPoint(90:\d){C0}

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(C0=2,B0=1) \tkzGetPoint{A1}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A0=2,C0=1) \tkzGetPoint{B1}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(B0=2,A0=1) \tkzGetPoint{C1}
\tkzInterLL(A0,A1)(B0,B1) \tkzGetPoint{A2}
\tkzInterLL(B0,B1)(C0,C1) \tkzGetPoint{B2}
\tkzInterLL(C0,C1)(A0,A1) \tkzGetPoint{C2}

%\clip (A0)--(B0)--(C0)--cycle;
\tkzDrawSegments(A0,A1 B0,B1 C0,C1)

\tkzDrawPolygon(A0,B0,C0)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A2,B2,C2)

\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](A0,B0,A2)
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](B0,C0,B2)
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=blue](C0,A0,C2)

\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](A2,B2,C2)
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](C2,B2,A2)
\tkzDrawCircle[in,color=red](B2,A2,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]